# Does Laravel Lumen runs on embedded machines?

Tags: c++, laravel, lumen

I need to develop a web interface for an embedded system and like to know if Laravel´s Lumen runs on tight memory/disk/Cpus. I don´t want to build plain HTML and I´m looking for a "serious and modern" framework to do so.

My current configuration is Vortex 800MHz processor/256Mb RAM and 1G disk. I´m running Sqlite3 as my database and some runtime C++ processes that takes about 20% of CPU. I[m running Ubuntu 12 on these units.

Lumen is going to be used to build the management interface, with no more than a few connections a day (very low usage).

Does anybody has experience running Lumen on that configuration that can be shared with me ?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Is 256 __KB__ right? I'm guessing you meant __MB__ because I doubt you could run Ubuntu in 256KB, let alone a web server. How much _free_ RAM do you have?

Comment: Yes, 256Mb. 256Kb today not even if you want to... Thanks for the correction...

Comment: I don´t know for now how much memory I have free as I haven´t installed the unit yet. I´m developing in a VM with 2Mb now. I will be installing a minimum Ubuntu version with no user interface. My stack will be minimal Ubuntu, Sqlite3, Apache2, Php and a framework (Lavarel Lumen?)

Comment: If you need something small and super fast you may want to check out [phalcon](https://phalconphp.com/en/). Although it's not as feature-rich as laravel, and personally I don't like it as much, it sounds about right for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, I don't think you can do it.

#### RAM

My basic LAMP stack with Laravel runs in ~200mb of RAM, so Lumen should run fine.  However, updating or installing Laravel via composer can use up to 512mb of RAM. I know Lumen is Laravel's *little* brother, so you might not need *as much*, but you'll definitely need some.

You could get around this by using a [swap file](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-12-04), but your swap file would need to be a least 250mb, if not more. Unfortunately, you just don't have the disk space for a swap file any larger than that.

#### Disk Space

I'm going to assume your 1G of disk space is actually 953mb because of [base-10 to base-2 conversion](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=1gb%20to%20mb).

According to [the docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/preparing-to-install.html#system-requirements), Ubuntu 12 requires ~500mb for a bare minimum install plus 500mb for the rest of the normal packages. I'll assume you can get away with the bare minimum of 500mb, mostly because I don't know what the *bare minimum* includes. You might need more.

Apache 2.2 [requires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/install.html#requirements) 50mb during install, but only 10mb after that.

My clean install of Lumen is 28mb.

Sqlite is [~1mb](https://www.sqlite.org/different.html).

I couldn't find a reference, but PHP is probably another 10mb.

So being extremely conservative, Ubuntu takes 500mb, Swap is 250mb, Apache is 10mb, Lumen is 28mb, Sqlite is 1mb, and PHP is 10mb for a total of **799mb**. That leaves you with **154mb** for extra packages required by those things, and various file downloads and expansions that occur during install.

I'm sure I'm leaving stuff out, and I'm sure you'll have to clear the apt cache after every install by running `sudo apt-get clean`.

You might also need to install the biggest stuff first and not create the swap file until you absolutely need it.

---

Overall, I think your best option is to spin up a VM with your hardware specs and try it out. Good luck, and report back with results.

Comment: Building the VM is on my plans.. Thanks for detailed info... I think even if I can install it all it will be too dense for such a small hardware... I need some performance also, so I have really to think about it all...